# Difference in vertical alignment of text in a div between browsers

Tags: css, html, text

I have a div in my html as follows:

```
<div class="questInfo">
   <div class="questBounty">100</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.questInfo {
  background-color: #fcfcfb;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.questBounty {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffedcc;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

When I view this in Safari, I get the following, as I intended:

[image: safari]

But in Firefox, the text appears to be pushed up:

[image: firefox]

Is there some attribute I should have set to achieve the former?

[A fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sjygD/)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but try setting `line-height` to match the height of your `div`. Also, please create a fiddle.

Comment: line-height* instead of lin-height

Comment: also, if it does not work try text-decoration:none;

Comment: It looks OK if I put it on its own in a web page in Firefox 21 and Chrome 26. Perhaps some other CSS rule is interfering here? Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Neither `line-height` nor `text-decoration` seem to work, I'm using Firefox 21. The `.questbounty` is itself within a `.questInfo` that I will add the CSS for above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think this can solve but try adding the 
-moz- in ur CSS 
That's support for Firefox

-moz-border-radius

-WebKit - has given support for safari so I think this should give for Firefox

Comment: It's my understanding that this was actually removed as of Firefox 13.0, and Firefox now responds to just border-radius. Is it common practice to add the prefix for backwards compatibility?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about that. I have not really tried tht coz normally I write these for all browsers while making a CSS